# How can I manage puppet agent nodes in the internal network from a puppet master in the internet?

Tags: automation, puppet

How can I manage puppet agent nodes in the internal network from a puppet master in the internet?

All the puppet agent nodes are within an internal network, thus do not have a unique ip for each of the agent node, however the puppet master node is in the internet, how can accomplish this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node's IP address doesn't participate in the authentication process to the puppet master. Also, master does not need to directly connect to nodes, since it's nodes responsibility to contact the master which then provides compiled catalog for each node.
What's important is that node's **FQDN** is unique among all the nodes managed by master. As far as:

- Puppet **master** can be reached via a known FQDN (by default configured to `puppet` on the agents, might be changed to a full domain name mapped to a public IP in your case)
- Puppet **agents** have access to Internet (or, more specifically, at least to the IP address of the Puppet master)
- Puppet **agents** have a ***unique*** fully qualified domain name configured on them (which you can see with `hostname -f`)

your master can manage your agents without special configuration.